# why does this function not return the excpected tsrange[]

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have these table with this dataset

```
CREATE TABLE  employee (entity_id uuid, valid tsrange);
INSERT into employee (entity_id, valid)
VALUES
('0006f79d-5af7-4b29-a200-6aef3bb0105f', tsrange('2009-05-23 02:00:00','2010-08-27 02:00:00')),
('0006f79d-5af7-4b29-a200-6aef3bb0105f', tsrange('2010-08-27 02:00:00','2010-10-27 02:00:00')),
('0006f79d-5af7-4b29-a200-6aef3bb0105f', tsrange('2011-05-23 02:00:00','infinity'))
```

for which I want to select an each continous aggregated `tsrange`, as an `tsrange[]`, as for a specific `entity_id`.

For this I have this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tsrange_cluster_aggregate(_tbl regclass, selected_entity_id uuid)
  RETURNS SETOF TSRANGE AS
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE
FORMAT(
 'SELECT tsrange(min(COALESCE(lower(valid), ''-infinity'')), max(COALESCE(upper(valid), ''infinity'')))
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(nextstart > enddate OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY valid DESC NULLS LAST) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT valid
           , max(COALESCE(upper(valid), ''infinity'')) OVER (ORDER BY valid) AS enddate
           , lead(lower(valid)) OVER (ORDER BY valid) As nextstart
      FROM %1$I
      where entity_id = %2$L
      ) a
   ) b
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY 1;'
, _tbl , selected_entity_id)
USING _tbl, selected_entity_id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT tsrange_cluster_aggregate('employee'::regclass, '0006f79d-5af7-4b29-a200-6aef3bb0105f');
```

Problem here is that output of this function is always empty?

I get the expected output when I run it outside an function?

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a09f8033091ea56e533880feebd0d5d4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `RETURN` in your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tsrange_cluster_aggregate(_tbl regclass, selected_entity_id uuid)
  RETURNS SETOF tsrange[] AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
FORMAT(
 ' SELECT array_agg(j) FROM (
SELECT tsrange(min(COALESCE(lower(valid), ''-infinity'')), max(COALESCE(upper(valid), ''infinity'')))
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(nextstart > enddate OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY valid DESC NULLS LAST) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT valid
           , max(COALESCE(upper(valid), ''infinity'')) OVER (ORDER BY valid) AS enddate
           , lead(lower(valid)) OVER (ORDER BY valid) As nextstart
      FROM %1$I
      where entity_id = %2$L
      ) a
   ) b
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY 1) z (j);'
, _tbl , selected_entity_id)
USING _tbl, selected_entity_id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f9ff2f3f4d6c5eccc11680790620666b)

Comment: how can I alter it to return an `tsrange[]`, adding the `array_agg` in similar was as the query does not seem to work?

Comment: Yes, but just have the function return it the `tsrange[]`